# Are Java operators always read left to right?

Tags: java, operators

Say we have a code like this:

```
int k=1;
System.out.println(k++ * ++k);
```

The output would be three and that's what my question is about. Is it always the case that Java, instead of first reading the whole line and separating pre-instructions from post-instructions thus treating it as:

```
int k=1;
k+=1;
System.out.println(k*k);
k+=1;
```

...just reads from left to right? Or is it compiler-dependent and shouldn't be relied upon?

Comment: It depends the operator type

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with the JVM and not `javac`?

Comment: multiplications and divisions take priority (when not used in the the parenthesis).

Comment: Matt Ball - I'm a newbie and that's what I assumed, sorry if that's wrong and thank you for clarification :)

Comment: You should have a look [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). They are always evaluated like that because unary and postfix operators have a higher precedence than multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined operator by operator by the language specification. In the case of your first example, the rule for the `*` operator is defined in [JLS 15.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17):

> The multiplicative operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

Comment: Thank you. However, there is no **k or //k, only ++k and --k so which operator would cause it to work some other way than left to right?

Comment: @Straightfw it's all in the JLS. Example: [the conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) is right-associative. Not joking: all I did was search for `right-associative`.

Comment: @Straightfw in `k++ * ++k` first `k++` is evaluated (because it is on the left), which returns 1, then `++k` is evaluated, which return 3 then the 2 are multiplied.

Answer (score 4):

```
k++ * ++k
```

is evaluated from left to right.

**Explanation:**

- `k++`: Use k's original value first (which is 1)
- Increment k after that, so now k is 2.
- `++k`: Increment k first and then use. So k is 3 now.

With k's initial value 1, `k++ * ++k` is becomes: `1 * 3` and result is 3.

Note that side-effects of sub-expressions are well-defined in Java which makes this expression valid in Java. An expression like `k++ * ++k` would cause undefined behaviour in C or C++. So avoid such expressions in general ;)

Comment: I understand how it evaluates, I just couldn't get why it doesn't read the whole line first and then first do the pre-things, then calculate, then do the post-things :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: It's evaluated left-to-right _because_ of the left-associativity of `*`.

Comment: @BlueMoon Why it would be undefined behavior in C or C++?

Comment: @iamcreasy C and C++ language specs says so: If an object is modified more than once without an intervening sequence point, it's undefined.